# How to get an .xlsx file from a Falcon resp.stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, falconframework

I'm trying to get the generated `.xlsx` file from the API.

I have the following code on the back-end:

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl import Workbook

@api_resource('/get_report')
class Report:
    @auth_required()
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active
        ws.title = "report"
        ws['C9'] = 'hello world'
        f = BytesIO()
        wb.save(f)
        f.seek(0)
        resp.stream = f
        resp.content_type = \
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
```

and the following code on the frontend:

```
ReportsAPI.getReport(filters).then(resp => {
 openXLS([resp.data], `report.xlsx`);
});

function openXLS(blob_data, filename) {
  let blob = new Blob(blob_data, {
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  });
  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.style = "display: none";
  link.href = url;
  link.download = filename;
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

I'm downloading the file via API request but the file is corrupted. If I save the file in the file system on the backend (```wb.save('test.xlsx')`

```
), the file opens without problems.

I tried to save the file as indicated in the documentation for openpyxl, but it does not work. 

...
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

wb = Workbook()
with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
     wb.save(tmp.name)
     tmp.seek(0)
     resp.stream = BytesIO(tmp.read())
```

What am I doing wrong?

In terminal `file -bi filename.xlsx` on normal file returns `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=binary`
, but on corrupted file it returns `application/zip; charset=binary`

I tried to make a request to API from the terminal

```
http  GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/get_report' > test.xlsx
```

and the file is not broken. It seems that the problem is on the front-end.

It seems to me that the problem is with the encoding, but I can not determine it.

Comment: Instead of adding "Resolved" in the title of your question, we invite you to post an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my request to api, I use axios and by default it always process data in JSON. Just needed to set the response type as arraybuffer

```
class ReportsAPI {
  getReport(filters) {
    return instance.get(`/get_report`, {
      params: { ...filters },
      responseType: "arraybuffer"
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is NOT python and get accepted ^^ What is this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting header to your response, like this:

```
def on_get(self, req, resp):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.title = "report"
    ws['C9'] = 'hello world'
    f = BytesIO()
    wb.save(f)
    f.seek(0)
    filename = 'sample.xlsx'
    resp.stream = f
    resp.content_type = \
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

    resp.set_header("Content-Disposition", f"attachment; filename={filename}")
```